# Create a new variable based in row values of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am new to R and not very familiar with the language.

I have a simple data frame in R. I'd like to add a blank column and then write some simple formulas to populate the new column for each row, based on the data in the columns of the respective row. Here is an example of the data frame:

```
ID Age BP Chl DM 
1 57 120 5 Y
2 87 134 7.5 N
3 95 111 6 Y
```

I would then like to add a new column, which would be populated with a formula. For example, for a given ID: if Age 40-59 AND BP 100-120 AND Chl <4 AND DM "N" = "10".

What package and function in R could I use to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: `?ifelse` might be a good place to start, perhaps `ifelse((dat$Age>=40 & dat$Age<=59 & dat$BP>=100 & dat$BP<=120 & dat$Chl<4 & dat$DM=="N"), 10, NA)`

Comment: Just to make it easy...you'll want to assign that to a new variable by declaring a new column in your dataframe....`yourdataframe$newvar <- ifelse((dat$Age>=40 & dat$Age<=59 & dat$BP>=100 & dat$BP<=120 & dat$Chl<4 & dat$DM=="N"), 10, NA)`

Comment: Get a book on R at your local library. I suggest Matloff's.

Comment: I'm getting it to work using 
    yourdataframe$newvar <- ifelse((dat$Age>=40 & dat$Age<=59 &   dat$BP>=100 & dat$BP<=120 & dat$Chl<4 & dat$DM=="N"), 10, NA)
(thank you @user3055034)
Is there a way that I can write this so that for each combination of the variable parameters, it puts the output in the same column, rather than adding a new column for each combination of variables?

Comment: tweaking @user3055034's comment: `dat <- transform(dat,newvar=if (Age>=40 & Age<=59 & BP>=100 & BP<=120 & Chl<4 & DM=="N") 10 else NA)`

Comment: Post solution as answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have three conditions:

1. Age > 50 & BP < 100
2. Age > 50 & BP >= 100
3. Age <=50

And you want to assing values `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, respectively, and store them in a new variable.

```
dat$newvar = NA # creates a new variable filled with NAs
ind1 = dat$Age > 50 & dat$BP < 100
ind2 = dat$Age > 50 & dat$BP >= 100
ind3 = dat$Age <=50

dat$newvar[ind1] = v1
dat$newvar[ind2] = v2
dat$newvar[ind3] = v3
```

You can use the same approach with as many conditions you want, just make sure the conditions are mutually excluyent. Rows not matching any condition will remain `NA`.